# WIX debug version "insufficient privileges to start service"

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I have built a WIX project which installs and starts services. For the release version it all seems to work fine but for the debug version I get "insufficient privileges to start service". Any clues why this is happening?

Using .net/Visual studio.

JD.

Comment: Um, does the person debugging have the ability to install and start a service?

Comment: @Will: It is an administrator account which is running the installer. This is on windows XP. So I built the installer in debug and then copied it to another machine and used the Administrator account to run the installer.

Comment: The error message says that your assumptions about account privileges on the other machine are incorrect.

Comment: @nobugz: With the debug installer I am running it on another machine where I am the administrator. Installing the service seems to work, it is just when the installer tries to start it that it rollsback (after waiting a few minutes). As I can install the service, the privileges seem fine, only the starting of it is causing a problem.

Comment: They are different privileges, installing a service only requires registry write access.  Also check http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg21330.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience this error message is always misleading.  Typically it's actually a fault of the service exe.    With the messagebox displayed,  go to a dos prompt and run the EXE.  You'll most likely see a stack trace get displayed.   If you see a File Not Found Exception then you are probably missing a dependency.  Any other error and it's likely to just be a problem with the code.

Typically when integrating a new service into my installs I will set it to start automatically but not author any specific start events.  This lets me work the kinks out with the developers before wiring it up fully into the installer.

Comment: Not clear why it happens on some machines and not others. On one machine I had to run the installer several times before it went through. For now, I will accept your answer, but will post if anything new comes to light. Thanks.

Comment: This is a really misleading message. Basically if the service crashes for any reason, it fails the install with this message. So if you have a db connection string incorrect and the service connects on start this will fail the install.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause: It works on computers that have (or have had) Visual Studio installed, because it means they have debug version of run-time libraries installed as well. It does not work on computers without Visual Studio.